# Why is my CALayer shadow blurry on retina displays when using shadowPath with shadowRadius set to 0?

Tags: ios, calayer, shadow, retina-display

I have a button which I'm adding a shadow to like this:

```
b.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.820 green:0.878 blue:0.941 alpha:1.000];
b.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
b.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2, 2);
b.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
b.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
```

That works great:

[image: retina shadow without shadow path]

If I use shadow path like so:

```
b.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:b.bounds cornerRadius:b.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;
```

The shadow is blurry on retina devices:

[image]

It's fine on non retina devices and seems to work correctly if `shadowRadius` isn't zero. I've tried setting `contentsScale` and `rasterizationScale` to 2 but it doesn't affect the shadow.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you ever came across a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of iOS 9.0 the `contentsScale` property of `CALayer` will also affect the rasterization scale of `shadowPath`. In other words, setting layer's `contentsScale` to screen scale will fix your issue.

Comment: Wow a blast from the past. Thanks Bartosz!